Gitlab merge PRs only if jenkins pipeline succeeded
I'm trying to sync my gitlab PRs with a jenkins pipeline.
I wish that for everytime someone opens a PR to branch "dev", a jenkins pipeline named "PRBuilder" will be triggered.
If that pipeline succeeds, then said PR will be able to be merged into dev, if the pipeline fails, I want to be notified in the gitlab UI and the PR will not be able to be merged into dev.
I looked for solutions online, but ran into a bunch of different answers which left me puzzled.

Looks like you're looking for a PR build. You will need to use the GitLab API for this.
Start off by creating a Jenkins job that polls the API to get the list of open PRs. Once you find an open PR, check if the destination branch is pointed to Dev (also available in API), then check if the PR has already been built (by looking at its build state which can also be taken from API).
Once you have determined that the PR is opened to dev, trigger a second build. This build will first update the build state of the GitLab PR to in-progress. This way, you can ensure the polling build doesn't try to rebuild this PR while another build is underway.
The second build will run, and depending on pass or fail, you can update the build state of the PR using the API. Then enable restrictions from GitLab so that only PRs with successful builds are allows to be merged.


Install GitLab Plugin in Jenkins

Configure Webhook in Gitlab
a. In your GitLab repository, go to Settings -> Webhooks.
b. Add a new webhook with the following details:

URL: http://<jenkins-server-url>/project/<your-job-name>
Trigger: Select Merge Request Events.


Send build notifications to GitLab PRs


post {
  success {
    script {
      // Notify GitLab about the success
      gitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'success'
    }
  }

  failure {
    script {
      // Notify GitLab about the failure
      gitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'failed'
    }
  }
}


This doesnt really work...
when I open a PR, the pipeline gets triggered, but the gitlab UI doesn't change in correspondence with the result of the pipeline (success/failure).
There is an additional requirement field named: "Merge request must be rebased, because a fast-forward merge is not possible", but this only works if I triggered the pipeline manually from the gitlab UI and if I add a new commit to the PR, then I can't triggered the pipeline manually from the gitlab UI again..
